# Error message exporting a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have created a raster using interpolation-TIN.
I tried to export it but I get the error message:

> Invalid creation option:
>   PREDICTOR=2 only valid for 8/16/32 bits per sample (using 64)
>   Click on help button to get valid creation options for this format

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error and changed to Predictor = 3 and it worked well for me. For more info on compress, deflate or predictor see below.

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

*"PREDICTOR=[1/2/3]: Set the predictor for LZW, DEFLATE and ZSTD compression. The default is 1 (no predictor), 2 is horizontal differencing and 3 is floating point prediction."*

Source: The link above.